# RowStyles and Rows doesn't match in TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

We are hiding controls in a `TableLayoutPanel`. We have been using the following code for a while for hiding a row that shouldn't be visible.

```
int controlRow = m_panel.GetPositionFromControl(control).Row;

m_panel.RowStyles[controlRow].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
m_panel.RowStyles[controlRow].Height = 0;
```

Now we have been adding more rows, and all of a sudden we have problems with the indexes.
There are fewer RowStyles than Rows.

[image: There are more rows than rowstyles. Screencap from debugging.]

Is there something fishy going on, or have I misunderstood how the `TableLayoutPanel` works?

Comment: Well, why not.  The RowCount assignment can certainly mismatch the number of RowStyles.Add() calls.  A screenshot doesn't help us help you find the bug.  Look at InitializeComponent if you used the designer, use the debugger if you used code.

Comment: I can't see any RowStyles being added by code at all. I think they are created implicitly. Those 2 rows above are all matches I get in all of the project searching for 'RowStyles'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tried digging into the issue. The problem is that you did not add rows in a correct way. To add rows correctly, you have to ensure the value of `RowCount` and the number of `RowStyles` to be equal. You can see this right in the `Form1.Designer.cs` in the autogenerated code for the tableLayoutPanel. So you should do something like this:

```
//add a new row
tableLayoutPanel.RowCount++;
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(newRowStyle);
```

The mismatching in fact does not cause a very serious problem. When the `RowStyles.Count` is larger than the actual `RowCount`, all the top RowStyles (which has count being equal to `RowCount`) will be used to style the rows, the rest can be seen as *reserve*. When the `RowStyles.Count` is smaller than the actual `RowCount`, there will be some rows not having any style and may be collapsed. Anyway using the code I posted above to add a new row will help you avoid any issue. The point is we have to ensure the number of rows and the number of `RowStyles` to be equal.

Comment: Does this mean that I can add a new rowstyle later on if neccesary? Like for instance just before I want to hide it?

Comment: This is an upgraded project that doesn't contain a Form.designer.cs file. It's all in Form.cs. Also, there are no RowStyles.Add in the whole project.

Comment: @CarlR As I said, you should keep your RowStyles and RowCount in sync, otherwise you may encounter some problem I mentioned at the end of my answer (which is not too serious).

Comment: I found there was an xml based TableLayoutSettings applied from the resx files. It ends like this literally: `&lt;Rows Styles="AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0,AutoSize,0" /&gt;&lt;/TableLayoutSettings&gt;`

Comment: Since there's even a space between `Rows Styles` it wasn't obvious to find. However thanks to your research I found it.

Thank you!